# How to test external rest call has been called twice?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec

I am writing RSpec test cases. I would like to test that an external endpoint has been called twice with the correct payload. But I can't seem to find a solution to my problem.

```
client = RealExternalAPI.new 

expect_any_instance_of(HTTP::Client).to(
   receive(:post).and_return(fake_api_response(status: 200))
)

expect_any_instance_of(HTTP::Client).to(
  receive(:post).and_return(fake_api_response(status: 200))
)


client.post_call(payload: 1)
client.post_call(payload: 2)
```

Here is an error message:

```
The message 'post' was received by #<HTTP::Client:2282816320 @default_options=#<HTTP::Options:0x0000000110220f40>, @connection=, @state=clean> but has already been received by #<HTTP::Client:0x0000000110223ee8>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use RSpec Message expectations [Receive counts](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/2-13/docs/message-expectations/receive-counts) helper to verify the call count

```
expect_any_instance_of(HTTP::Client).to(
  receive(:post).twice.and_return(fake_api_response(status: 200))
)
```